# How to solve 'Connection timed out' error in SSH connection raspberry pi4?

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi

I have raspberry pi4 running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I'm making SSH connections to it from my PC with windows10. Most of the times I can connect to it very easily but some times I get **'Connection timed out'** errors.

Also restarting pi after this error I can connect to it but still I need to figure out what's causing this

How to solve this?